# Writing binary data to Buffer

Tags: node.js, binary, hex

Normally, I would expect that the following would be good enough to represent binary data in a Buffer:

```
new Buffer('01001000','binary')
```

but I am pretty certain Node.js/JS does not support this 'binary' encoding. 
What is the best way then to write binary data to a buffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do binary encoding like this:

```
 var binaryString = "\xff\xfa\xc3\x4e";
 var buffer = new Buffer(binaryString, "binary");
 console.log(buffer);
 <Buffer ff fa c3 4e>
```

//types of encoding allowed

```
encoding            size (bytes) 
base64                 4,177,241 
binary                   4,162,398 
hex                       4,669,965 
JSON                   2,271,670 
utf16le*                4,543,605 
utf8*                     3,640,132 
ascii*                    2,929,850
```

Comment: thanks! do you have a reference where I can read about what this format is: "\xff\xfa\xc3\x4e"? What is that?

Comment: ok so my guess is that this is hex and that \x is equivalent to 0x

Comment: exactly you got it :)